# Ltac pattern matching: why does `forall x, ?P x` not match `forall x, x`?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, ltac

```
Ltac checkForall H :=
  let T := type of H in
  match T with
  | forall x, ?P x =>
    idtac
  | _ =>
    fail 1 "not a forall"
  end.

Example test : (forall x, x) -> True.
Proof.
  intros H.
  Fail checkForall H. (* not a forall *)
Abort.
```

I would naively expect `checkForall H` to succeed, but it doesn't.

In his book *Certified Programming with Dependent Types*, Adam Chlipala [discusses](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Cpdt.Match.html#lab89) a limitation of pattern matching on dependent types:

> The problem is that unification variables may not contain locally bound variables.

Is this the reason for the behaviour I'm seeing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As larsr explained, the pattern `?P x` can only match a term that is syntactically an application, which does not cover the case you are considering. However, Ltac does provide features for the match you are looking for.  As the [user manual](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/ltac.html) says:

> There is also a special notation for second-order pattern-matching problems: in an applicative pattern of the form `@?id id1 …idn`, the variable id matches any complex expression with (possible) dependencies in the variables `id1 …idn` and returns a functional term of the form `fun id1 …idn => term`.

Thus, we can write the following proof script:

```
Goal (forall x : Prop, x) -> False.
intros H.
match goal with
| H : forall x : Prop, @?P x |- _ => idtac P
end.
```

which prints `(fun x : Prop => x)`.

Answer (score 2):

The type of H is `forall x, x`, not `forall x, P x`.

```
Ltac checkForall H :=
  let T := type of H in
  match T with
  | forall x, ?P x =>
    idtac
  | forall x, x =>
    idtac "this matches"
  | _ =>
    fail 1 "not a forall"
  end.

Example test : (forall x, x) -> True.
Proof.
  intros H.
  checkForall H. (* not a forall *)

Abort.
```

or to match your `checkForall`

```
Example test {T} (f:T->Prop)  : (forall x, f x) -> True.
Proof.
  intros H.
  checkForall H.
```

Comment: I would add that `?P x` represents an [application](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual003.html#applications), whereas `x` is an [identifier](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual003.html#qualid). They are syntactically different and cannot be unified.